# How do I insert a node as first element within a for loop?

Tags: xquery, basex

I get the following error:

[XUST0001](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/#ERRXUST0001) element constructor: no updating expression allowed.

When trying to insert **insert nodes test as first into $c**

I feel like my code is following the [examples](http://www.xmlmind.com/tutorials/XQueryUpdate/) I see online although clearly I've got something wrong.

How do I insert a node with a `for` loop?

```
declare namespace db="http://basex.org/modules/db";
declare namespace file="http://expath.org/ns/file";
declare variable $form13FFileNumber as xs:string external;

let $data := db:open('13F')//data[contains(edgarSubmission/formData/coverPage/form13FFileNumber,$form13FFileNumber)]

let $fields := 

<form13FFile>
{
for $c in $data return 
insert nodes <b4>test</b4> as first into $c  
}
</form13FFile>

return file:write(concat('../OUT/' , $form13FFileNumber , '.xml'), $fields)
```

To be more clear my xml looks something like

```
   <data>
     <first_Child>text</first_child>
   </data>
   <data>
     <first_Child>text</first_child>
   </data>
```

and I would like it to adjust to

```
<form13FFile>
    <data>
     <b4>test</b4>
     <first_Child>text</first_child>
    </data>
    <data>
     <b4>test</b4>
     <first_Child>text</first_child>
    </data>
</form13FFile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I have already answered "offline", but for reference I'm also putting my suggestion here]

I think what you need is a copy-modify-return expression, which is how you create updated copies.

```
let $fields :=
<form13FFile>
{
  for $c in $data
  return 
    copy $new-node := $c
    modify insert nodes <b4>test</b4> as first into $new-node
    return $new-node  
}
</form13FFile>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to create a new result set: you don't need XQuery Update here at all! XQuery Update is great if you want to change existing documents, but not required at all when constructing new ones.

```
<form13FFile>
{
for $c in $data return 
<b4>test</b4>
}
</form13FFile>
```

Or if you want to stick with the `as first` semantics (I expect the static test element will change in future), reverse `$data` before looping:

```
<form13FFile>
{
for $c in reverse($data) return 
<b4>test</b4>
}
</form13FFile>
```

Comment: Hi Jens, I've adjusted my question to be more clear by adding the example of what I would like the xml to look like. The result of your solution is <form13FFile><b4>test</b4></form13FFile> which is not quite what I'm looking for. Sorry the question wasn't clear.